# How to keep GOTO :EOF but bypass it to finish the rest of the script?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

Please look at this code below. It works but at the **goto :EOF** it stops the script and doesn't complete what is below it. Is there a work around? There of course is more to this script but the goto :EOF needs to be there in order for it to work.

```
:stripdup

 >_.vbs echo set regex=new regexp
>>_.vbs echo regex.global=true
 >>_.vbs echo regEx.IgnoreCase=False
 >>_.vbs echo regex.pattern="%~3"
>>_.vbs echo wscript.stdOut.write regex.replace(wscript.stdin.readall,"%~4")
cscript /nologo _.vbs <"%~1" >"%~2"

del _.vbs

goto :EOF

 del Campaign_RND.mis

copy Campaign_RND.mis.tmp Campaign_RND.mis

del Campaign_RND.mis.tmp


del "C:\Users\P Ditty\Documents\SH3\data\cfg\Backups_RND" /q

rd "C:\Users\P Ditty\Documents\SH3\data\cfg\Backups_RND"




tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq sh3.exe" | find /i "sh3.exe"  
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO TEST2 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO TEST1  
:TEST2 
goto start 
:TEST1 
exit
```

Comment: The "GOTO :eof" is there to end the script. There is no work around other than to take it out. Unless of course you want to call :stripdup and then go to the code after it finishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the GOTO to work in some cases and be omitted in others, then you need to make your jump *conditional*:

```
IF condition GOTO :EOF
```

At this point only you can say what this condition must be.

Answer (score 3):

```
goto :EOF
```

is going to do exactly that every time!  You will need to restructure your code if you need to do something else.

Comment: I figured it out. I put a goto just above it that pointed below the goto:EOF in the code.